# What is the ideal jetty.xml configuration to avoid "Broken Pipe" or "EofException " exception?

Tags: java, jetty

I'm new to jetty and have started using it month back as an embedded server in OSGi framework. Lately, I'm observing few "Broken Pipe" and "End of File" exceptions.

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:911)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.4.1.v20110513] 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.flushResponse(HttpConnection.java:753)[82:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.4.1.v20110513] 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Output.close(HttpConnection.java:1124)[82:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.4.1.v20110513] 
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:606)[96:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.4.0.fuse-00-27] 
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)[96:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.4.0.fuse-00-27] 
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:549)[96:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.4.0.fuse-00-27] 
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)[96:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.4.0.fuse-00-27] 
    ... 36 more 

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe 
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_14] 
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)[:1.6.0_14] 
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:104)[:1.6.0_14] 
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)[:1.6.0_14] 
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)[:1.6.0_14] 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:240)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.4.1.v20110513] 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:282)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.io:7.4.1.v20110513] 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:855)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.http:7.4.1.v20110513]
```

Initially, I bumped up the linux "ulimit" but it didn't completely address the issue, except for the frequency of error. The current load to the server is around 500 requests/sec. My current jetty.xml is bare minimum and doesn't specify any threadpool or acceptor value. Just wondering, if improper configuration is causing a problem resulting jetty to refuse connections. Here's what I've.

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8010"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">20000</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
```

I'm not sure what default value jetty uses for acceptors or threadpool. I looked into the documentation but failed to find anything relevant.

I tried adding a threadpool but had the same problem. Here's the threadpool entry:

```
<Set name="ThreadPool">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
    <Set name="minThreads">30</Set>
    <Set name="maxThreads">3000</Set>
  </New>
</Set>
```

I'll appreciate if someone can provide pointers to this issue. I'm running jetty version 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

BrokenPipe and EofException are a result of many changes in the web landscape.

Such as fixes for the SSL Half Close vulnerability, and even the increasing use of the web from mobile endpoints (laptops, tablets, mobile phones) that also exacerbate this issue.

The jetty version you are using 7.4.1 does not yet have the noise reduction for these conditions (mostly harmless, but only in a small set of circumstances.  such as the client stating "Connection: keep-alive", but then closing the connection after performing only 1 full request/response transaction)

Starting with jetty 7.6.0 (currently in 7.6.0.RC3) the noise from these exceptions during known harmless conditions are being filtered out.